# Porque sale este error al obtener URL firmadas de AWS S3?

Tags: nodejs, aws, amazon-s3

Estoy aprendiendo a usar AWS, principalmente S3, estoy subiendo imágenes, ya tengo un código para subir las imágenes. Estoy usando NodeJS con express, en fin, mi objetivo es obtener la url de ese objeto, pero entiendo que debe ser firmada, leí la documentación y me mostró esta dependencia `@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner`, hasta ahí todo bien, el problema viene cuando ya quiero firmar la url, me regresa una url, pero al usarla sale este error:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Ahora mi método para firmar la url es el siguiente:

```
async function signAWSLinks(archivo){
    const params = {
         Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
         Key: archivo.originalname
    }
    const command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
    return await getSignedUrl(client, command, {expiresIn:3600})
}
```

Y este regresa una promesa la cual manejo de la siguiente forma en mi ruta: `router.post("/firmar", upload.single('archivo') ,al.firmar);` :

```
signAWSLinks(archivo).then((res)=>{
    console.log(res)
})
```

Ahorita solo lo tengo así por motivos de prueba y depuración, la variable archivo vaya, recibe el archivo usando multer y ya solo hago lo siguiente en el controlador de la firma de url `const archivo = req.file;` y listo lo mando a la función anterior. La verdad ya no entiendo donde puede estar mal, la propia documentación hace exactamente lo que yo hice en la función, intente ver videos y hacen lo mismo.

Mi client es el siguiente:

```
const client = new S3Client({
region: process.env.REGION, // Por ejemplo, 'us-east-1'
credentials:{
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
}
});
```

Y no puede estar mal o eso creo, ya que con este mismo en otra función es el que ocupo para subir las imágenes. Y si entendí bien, solo basta con el bucket, el nombre del archivo y la conexión al cliente para firmar la url. Gracias si puedes ayudarme, y si no me explique bien tambien dimelo

Comment: Es posible que estés modificando el nombre del archivo en algún momento? Cuando generas una presigned la estás asociando a un recurso en concreto y no vale para descargarse/subir otro diferente. Si cambia algo entonces la presigned no sirve